# How to remove "Generation date" from auto-generated LightSwitch class

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

i have auto-generated LightSwitch class

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.17929
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Original file name:
// Generation date: 12.09.2013 16:12:15
namespace LightSwitchApplication.Implementation
{

}
```

Each build change "Generation date" and i have to commit this file to svn or revert it. How to delete this row?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you **can't** delete anything from any of the files that LightSwitch **generates**. If you did so in some automated manner, your changes would simply be overwritten again the next time you build the project.

But, there's no need for any generated files to be stored in source control. So rather than trying to remove a line from the files, just use SVN's settings to exclude any folders that have the word "generated" in them (or any other way to exclude the files).

If you were to restore a LightSwitch project from source control (that doesn't have the generated files), LightSwitch will simply re-generate those files.